# Ubuntu Desktop does not load

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz

If I login on my Ubuntu 14.04, I get the following desktop:[image: Desktop]

This weird behavior appeared after I executed `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and restarted my computer. Don't know why though.

To my Ubuntu I have tried the following (nothing seems to work so far)

*Fix any broken packages:*

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*Locate any broken packages and reinstall them:*

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo apt-get clean
sudo debsums_init
sudo debsums -cs
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(sudo dpkg -S $(sudo debsums -c) | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u)
```

*Removing some compiz files:*

```
rm -r ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
rm -r ~/.compiz
```

*Purging of NVIDIA and installing NVIDIA-prime:*

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
sudo shutdown -r now
```

*Compizconfig Settings Manager:*

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm

// Back to UI and enablement of Unity Plugin
```

*Unity replace, which stopped at a while and did nothing afterwards*

```
unity --replace
```

*Some dconf reset*

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

**Actually dconf did not work and I got this error:**

```
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Can anybody help me on that?

---

This is my hardware (hope it helps in any way):

- Intel® Core™ i7-3770
- ASUS GTX660TI-DC2-OG-2GD5 ([NVIDIA driver is/was installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver))
- ASUS P8Z77-V LX
- Corsair DIMM 8 GB DDR3-1600 Kit
- Samsung 830series 2,5" 256 GB (Windows is installed here)
- Seagate ST31000524AS 1 TB (3/4 are reserved for files; 1/4 is for Ubuntu (16GB swap included))

Comment: @karel: Niklas already tried all the answers in the linked question unsuccessfully.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't have any way of knowing for sure that Niklas has already tried all 50 answers to the question that I linked to, since Niklas didn't say that, although he did say he tried a few different things.

Answer (score 18):

I have had the exact same problem since yesterday as well. To fix it I had to install gnome-panel then run unity reset through unity tweak tools.

1. Switch to a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), log in and run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
   sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
   ```
2. Reboot and select gnome on login.
3. Once logged in open a terminal (e. g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
   ```
4. Log out and log in again using Unity this time and that fixed it for me.

Comment: That did not quite work out for me. How can I select gnome on login? I just saw my default login view. `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` and I get `failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

Comment: I executed `export DISPLAY=:0` and then `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` and got this error message back `dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=<some_uuid> --binary-syntax --close-stderror': Child process exited with code 1`.

Comment: You have to click on the little ubuntu logo next to your name at login. It will only appear after installing gnome.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I've been dead in the water for 2 hours!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate answer :)

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't do this because i couldn't enter the terminal.
So i do this:
Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
$ sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
```

Reboot and select gnome login instead of ubuntu default before writing your password to login.
once logged in open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
$ dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
$ setsid unity
```

Reboot again

After that I could enter in ubuntu default login normally

Links:
[Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load)
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I had to press ctrl + alt + the instead of ctrl + t

Answer (score 2):

```
chown -R <your user>:<your group> ~/.dbus
```

from [GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running?! How to reinstall or fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135573/gconf-error-no-d-bus-daemon-running-how-to-reinstall-or-fix)

was useful to me in case of the "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY" error

Comment: This plus the unity-tweak-tool reset worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Few minutes ago had this problem. Fix this too easy)) Just check your unity `unity` and terminal said you some like `You have not unity, install it`. Do that: `sudo apt-get install unity` and after installing write `unity` again. Desktop will be laucnhed.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english))

P.P.S.If  Ctrl + Alt + T doesnt work press CTRL + ALT + F1

Comment: The problem is not that Unity is not installed. It IS installed, and is crashing. That's why this question has not been upvoted.

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't see the files and folders that are on the desktop. I load the start bar with the icons and compiz but I can't see the folders and files on the desktop. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue. Reinstalling the NVIDIA driver fixed my problem. But first install the dkms package and then reinstall the NVIDIA driver. So no need to recompile the NVIDIA modules for the latest kernel everytime you update it.

Comment: How can I install the DKMS packages?

Comment: @Niklas `sudo apt-get install dkms` . After installing this, you may need to restart your system for the installation to take effect.

Comment: dkms packages are already installed, since I have reinstalled the NVIDIA driver a thousand times, your solution does not work on my case.