# Ubuntu 14.04 desktop does not load after login

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lightdm

I have a Asus Notebook (X450L) with Ubuntu 14.04, it has a nvidia card 720m and a Intel HD Video onboard. All working just fine until yesterday, when I updated the system.

Now, after the login screen, I've got a screen stucked like that:

[image]

I've tried all that is on this topic: [Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930) , but none of that really works for me :(

I've also tried to reinstall lightdm and, after that, dpkg-reconfigure lightdm.

Obviously, I've tried too removing all nvidia driver and reinstalling them... nothing works... I'm really upset with this, can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Disable the NVidia card in the BIOS or if you have a PC: remove the NVidia card.  Then repeat [Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930) again...