# Ubuntu doesn't boot after bleachbit

Tags: boot, xorg, bleachbit

I used bleachbit on my Ubuntu 14.10 system. After that I restarted the system and I get this message:

```
 SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: diabled, see /etc/default/spamassassin
 * speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 SSL tunnels disabled, see /etc/default/stunnel4
 * Starting tor daemon...
 * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...
 * Autostart disabled, no VPN will be started.
 saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned

 (process:3298): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunc D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I can still log in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> into a terminal session...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load

Comment: I tried everything recommendet there but nothing worked and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by logging into a terminal session and resinstalling the xserver:

```
 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg`
```

Comment: The symptoms and resolution seem unrelated to BleachBit, but if it is reproducible, please [report a bug with the BleachBit version and options used](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/help)

Comment: Sorry but I am not running it again to get the same horrible issue :), but it was the only program I run or installed before restarting, so I couldn't think of something else that might have caused it

Comment: Have you recently updated through apt? The document that shaddy link describes a situation triggered by updating through apt.

Comment: No, I did not update my system besides the usual Software Updates of the programs (but not on that day) and I downloaded bleachbit from the website and it was the version for Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Did you have a successful reboot after the last usual Software Update?

Comment: Yes, no problems probably it has anything to do with my 'special' system since I have an SSD and an HDD, on the HDD I have /home and /usr/share/

Comment: Very wise!  Don't use BleachBit any more!  It causes more problems then it solves!

Comment: Do u have a suggestion for an alternative?