# Cannot login to tty / Login incorrect / Unity Launcher and Menu Bar disappeared in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, tty

I'm facing the same (or similar) issue as described here: [Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04)

Unfortunately I cannot try the provided solution (https://askubuntu.com/a/476623), as I fail to log in. I always get `Login incorrect`.

I already checked my password by typing it in as login name. Everything is correct. No caps, no num. I also have no problems getting to my desktop with my user name and password. Could it be due to my username `Stefan Schmid` with a space?

The System is 14.04 LTS. On the login screen there is still the menu bar. I even can get to settings. But thats about it. E.g: when I click on `users`, nothing happens.

What should I do?

Comment: Usually when creating a user with a space in the name, the username is truncated after the space. Try logging into TTY1 using just `stefan` as the username.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped so far with the login. But I could have sworn, I tried that one before.

Comment: And thats what helped me to bring unity back: http://askubuntu.com/a/477752/483151

Answer (score 1):

You may be using the wrong username. As usernames do not usually contain spaces or capitals, the username that is created for you is different than the name that appears on the LightDM log-in screen.

To solve, log-in to TTY1 using just `stefan` as the username, and then follow the instructions in the other question for the rest of your issue.