# Unity fails to start session [after removing gnome]

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

EDIT : I can login through `tty` but GUI session is failing to start.
Most answers on the net recommend installing gnome again. I don't want to do that if there is a more logical solution.

This is an old question and the reason for it is old as well. I installed GNOME, used it for a few weeks but didn't like the lag, so removed it using these commands:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3    
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then tried to install `ubuntu-desktop`, which required `ubuntu-session`, which required some downgrading.

But the problem persists. How do I use Unity short of reinstalling gnome again? I really have very bad download speeds.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, although I have gnome bits lying around now-

[Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load)

basically, reinstall `gnome-panel` and `unity-tweak-tool` and then reset unity.