# Unity not starting in 16.04

Tags: unity

I use Ubuntu 16.04 under VirtualBox. Today I updated VirtualBox to 5.0.26. After it I updated the Ubuntu using GUI, but the update has frozen during grub update. After reset, it started normally and I finished the update manually from command line.

Now, after logging in the Unity does not start. I can reach the terminal via popup menu and start the Unity manually via the terminal using "unity -v" command. Interestingly without the "-v" option the unity does not start. I tried to reinstall unity and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-does-not-load) without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears):

this worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```