# Ubuntu Desktop not loading after login and nothing works

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

ISSUE:-

Desktop doesn't load and can only access OS using alt+ctrl+f1

ALREADY TRIED:-

[Ubuntu Desktop does not load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476930/ubuntu-desktop-)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

ccsm took a long time and showed nothing on command line so i stopped it with ctrl+z

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity --replace
```

did nothing too

[Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

MY PC:-

Ubuntu 16 LTS
graphics card - radeon amd a8
laptop - HP

THINGS I DID LAST BEFORE THE CRASH :-

I was earlier having issues with linking my IDE with the server and JDK so I first learnt that (using trial and error method generally involving depaclaging jdk here and there and trying to set environmrnt variables and everything but never touched tools like unity that came into picture now)

although i had installed gnome tweak tool using the package manager and used it to reduce my icon sizes and things like that

I recently depackaged eclipse, apache server, jdk (all three files extracted on desktop itself and also the eclipse workspace) and had successfully run my first servlet and had switched the laptop off

but after that the desktop never loaded back

I dont even mind resetting the complete OS I just don't want to lose my project files which i was going to import in eclipse to develop my project.