# cannot use visual mode GUI through ssh -XY <ip_address>

Tags: server, ssh, gui

I am using ubuntu 12.04, and I am trying to ssh to log into a remote server which is also running ubuntu 12.04.

I am using "ssh -X ". I can log into the remote server smoothly, but cannot use the visual/graphical mode to open an application with GUI.

I think the problem lies in this server itself. Because I can use "ssh -X" to run GUI when connecting to another remote server. But I am not sure how to configure it to make it work.

**echo $DISPLAY** returns blank. Using grep X11 on **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file returns:

➜  ~  cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no

I have read the following posts, but the problem is still unsolved, 
[gedit "cannot open display" , on remote computer , using ssh - Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180893/gedit-cannot-open-display-on-remote-computer-using-ssh-ubuntu-12-04)
[Problem with X can not open display while ssh from ubuntu 13.04 to centos servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326519/problem-with-x-can-not-open-display-while-ssh-from-ubuntu-13-04-to-centos-server?rq=1)

Hope to get help from you. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have found this post: [Run application on local machine and show GUI on remote display](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203173/run-application-on-local-machine-and-show-gui-on-remote-display)

Comment: Can you show an example error message you get when trying to run your application GUI after logging in? Does your environment have a `DISPLAY` variable, what does `echo $DISPLAY` show on your server login? Do you have root on the server, are you able to look into and/or edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the server?

Comment: @mtmiller echo $DISPLAY shows nothing on the server machine. I can look into **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file on the server, I can also ask for a root permission from my boss.

Comment: @mtmiller Here is an example of running GUI after logging in. I am trying to open a text file using gnome-open, the default editor is gedit. It shows the following ERROR:  
**(gnome-open:24569)**: GConf-WARNING : Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running  

**(gedit:24572)**: WARNING: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=d351af25c7aa104bf2c6af1600000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed. Cannot open display

Comment: @Letizia, Thanks for providing this useful link. I think ssh are installed both on the server and my local machine, and I do use "ssh -X usrname@serverIP". But I am unable to open any GUI remotely. For instance, if I type in "firefox" after logging in the server, it simply shows: *Error: no display specified*. I have read the link you shared, but **echo $DISPLAY** shows nothing for me.

Comment: try set in .bashrc on server DISPLAY=ipRemoteDesktop:0.0

Comment: @Letizia . I did what you said just now. But I am having the same errors as described in the upper comment.

Comment: sorry, the right code is: export DISPLAY=ipRemoteDesktop:0.0
After that, source .bashrc or re-login

Comment: @Letizia, I did exactly what you told. **(gnome-open:27326): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.  

GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running

No protocol specified

** (gedit:27330): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=d351af25c7aa104bf2c6af1600000007 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: No protocol specified. Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

Comment: I have found another post [GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running?! How to reinstall or fix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135573/gconf-error-no-d-bus-daemon-running-how-to-reinstall-or-fix). Verify ~/.dbus permission and ownership. Check it on the server where X-session works.

Comment: @Letizia, I tried these links provided. But the problem is still there. The server has Nvidia GPUs, I believe there might be some issue with the GPU. No matter how I configure the DISPLAY environment, the remote GUI display doesn't work. I am wondering if you have more suggestions?

Comment: @mtmiller,the server has Nvidia GPUs, I believe there might be some issue with the GPU. No matter how I configure the DISPLAY environment, the remote GUI display doesn't work. I am wondering if you have more suggestions?

Comment: Check in /var/log if are present errors and add information to your question. In /var/log are present a lot of file, so try "ls -lrt" and verify if they change date and time after your command.

Comment: use [dbus-monitor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingDBus) that display information about dbus activity. Check [X-session](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/Xsession.5.html) configuration between the two server (/etc/X11/Xsession) and verify if present  ~/.Xsession-error (exec ls -la  ~/)