# How to fix "EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro"

Tags: boot

I saw this in the system log: `EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro`. What is the meaning of this error?

How to fix it?

---

Relevant output:

```
$ dmesg | grep mount
[    1.515956] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.750742] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg | grep mount`?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan See the edit.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not an error, it just tells you that the partition `/dev/sda1` has been remounted with the mount option `errors=remount-ro`. It's nothing you need to worry about. It may happen e.g. during a normal system startup if `/dev/sda1` is your root partition.

The mount option means that the system should mount the partition read-only if an error occurs to minimize further damage or data loss and is used by default.

Comment: But why does it mount for then to remount the partition - is do to initramfs?

Comment: My Lubuntu 18.04.1 does not shut down properly. The last entry in the shut-down log produced as described in the "Debugging boot/shutdown problems" section of /usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian.gz says 'EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro'. Could that be causing problem described by another user in https://askubuntu.com/q/620132/288322? Thanks for a hint!

Comment: Ya I have the exact same problem, except I'd swear its some sort of software issue not an actual disk problem.